# Spring RabbitTemplate.execute hangs when queue is down

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am trying to execute get server properties to assert on health of RabbitMQ channel. Here is my code:

```
rabbitTemplate.execute(new ChannelCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public String doInRabbit(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> serverProperties = channel.getConnection()
                            .getServerProperties();
                    return serverProperties.get("version").toString();
                }
            });
```

However when I deliberately stop rabbit mq and then execute this method, it hangs forever instead of timing out.

Is there a way to assert on liveliness & connectivity of the RabbitMQ?

Taking thread dump, the state of the thread is TIMED_WAITING

Here is the thread dump.

```
"http-nio-4300-exec-1@9154" daemon prio=5 tid=0x2f nid=NA sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-1)
      at org.springframework.retry.backoff.ThreadWaitSleeper.sleep(ThreadWaitSleeper.java:29)
      at org.springframework.retry.backoff.FixedBackOffPolicy.doBackOff(FixedBackOffPolicy.java:83)
      at org.springframework.retry.backoff.StatelessBackOffPolicy.backOff(StatelessBackOffPolicy.java:36)
      at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:293)
      at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:172)
      at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1353)
      at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1346)
      at com.myfavcompany.microservice.monitoring.MyMicroServiceRabbitHealthIndicator.health(MyMicroServiceRabbitHealthIndicator.java:25)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:81)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.getHealth(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:166)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:140)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
      - locked <0x24db> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you take a thread dump when it's in that state? I get a `Connection Refused` exception...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46776458Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46776458Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(rabbitTemplate.execute(new ChannelCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                public String doInRabbit(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> serverProperties = channel.getConnection().getServerProperties();
                    return serverProperties.get("version").toString();
                }

            }));
        };
    }

}

2017-10-16 15:41:24.935 ERROR 14375 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:726) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:713) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.So46776458Application.main(So46776458Application.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.example.So46776458Application.lambda$0(So46776458Application.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:723) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will work on giving you the thread dump, once I have access to application.

Comment: This is a frustrating point and it is making our design lot more complicated. If only it readily threw an exception, life would be far simpler.

Comment: The state is insufficient. Need a dump to see where it is hung.

Comment: added the logs. Please find it attached to the question

Comment: It appears you have configured a `RetryTemplate` into your `RabbitTemplate` - so, of course, the template will block, according to your retry policy, until retries are exhausted. `at org.springframework.retry.backoff.FixedBackOffPolicy.doBackOff(FixedBackOffPolicy.java:83)`. If you don't want that, don't add retry, or configure a faster backoff.

Comment: We don't us spring AMQP but For what it's worth even if you do configure retry handler correctly I don't recommend trying to handle timeouts but instead fail fast and stop the application.